# My sql query was aborted but the free disk space wasn't restored; Why?

Tags: mysql, sql, windows, memory

I was creating a table on mysql, but since I'm working with a large amount of data, I aborted the query to clean up the memory. But, during this little time, the query took some memory and after aborting the query, this space was not restored. Where is it?

I'm using Windows 10, ASUS VivoBook and MySQL 8.0

Comment: Well its possible that when you ran the query, MySQL stored some query results to memory. If a lot of memory is being used, then you can try to restart the MySQL server

Comment: @NadirLatif I restarted the MySQL server (in services) and I also restarted my computer, but the memory was not restored yet.

Comment: If your computer is taking up a lot of memory, then you should run the Task Manager and find out which process is taking up the memory. If MySQL server is taking up a lot of memory, then you need to tune the MySQL server configuration

Comment: The problem was solved! I'm using Innodb in my MySQL and so that I have to optimize the table, because Innodb doesn't free the free disk. Thank you very much for you help.